# How do you create Order with Magento API?

Tags: magento-1.8, api

First of all i am working on this for past 3 days and still don't know what is causing this issue.

Following is the code.

```
$api_url = 'Soap URl';

$api_user = 'User';
$api_key = 'API key';

$proxy = new SoapClient($api_url);

    try {
  $sessionId = $proxy->login($api_user, $api_key);  
  $customers = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'customer.list', array(array('email' => 'testing123456@gmail.com')));  
  if(count($customers) == 0 ){  
    $customer_data = array(
        'email' => 'testing123456@gmail.com',
        'firstname' => 'ritesh',
        'lastname' => 'patadiya',
        'password' => 'test1234',
        'website_id' => 1,
        'store_id' => 1,
        'group_id' => 1
      );

    $customer = $proxy->call($sessionId,'customer.create',array($customer_data));
  }
  else{
    $customer = $customers[0];
  }
  $customer['mode'] = 'customer';
  $shoppingCartId = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'cart.create', array('1'));

  try{
    $resultCustomerSet = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'cart_customer.set', array($shoppingCartId, $customer));
  } catch (Exception $ex){
    echo "cart customer set = ".$ex->getMessage();
  }

  $arrAddresses = array(
     array(
          "mode" => "shipping",
          "firstname" => "ritesh",
          "lastname" => "patadiya",
          "company" => "rb",
          "street" => "wall street",
          "city" => "rajkot",
          "region" => "gujarat",
          "postcode" => "4567892",
          "country_id" => "id",
          "telephone" => "0123456789",
          "fax" => "0123456789",
          "is_default_shipping" => 0,
          "is_default_billing" => 0
      ),
      array(
          "mode" => "billing",
          "firstname" => "ritesh",
          "lastname" => "patadiya",
          "company" => "rb",
          "street" => "wall street",
          "city" => "rajkot",
          "region" => "gujarat",
          "postcode" => "123456",
          "country_id" => "id",
          "telephone" => "0123456789",
          "fax" => "0123456789",
          "is_default_shipping" => 0,
          "is_default_billing" => 0
      )
  );

  try{
    $resultCustomerAddresses = $proxy->call($sessionId, "cart_customer.addresses", array($shoppingCartId, $arrAddresses));
  } catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo '<br />cart_customer.addresses'.$ex->getMessage();
  }

// Disable shipping method when product is virtual.

//  try{
//    $resultShippingMethods = $proxy->call($sessionId, "cart_shipping.list", array($shoppingCartId));
//    $shippingMethod = $resultShippingMethods[0]["code"];
//    $resultShippingMethod = $proxy->call($sessionId, "cart_shipping.method", array($shoppingCartId, $shippingMethod));
//  } catch(Exception $ex){
//    echo '<br />cart_shipping.method'.$ex->getMessage();
//  }

  $arrProducts = array(
    array(
//      "sku" => "FBP001" // This is virtual product, we have modified price to 0.01
      "sku" => "DEM001R" // This is virtual product, we have modified price to 0.01
    )
  );  


  try{
    $resultCartProductAdd = $proxy->call($sessionId, "cart_product.add", array($shoppingCartId, $arrProducts));
  }
  catch(Exception $ex){
     echo '<br />cart_product.add'.$ex->getMessage();
  }

  try{
    $resultPaymentMethods = $proxy->call($sessionId, "cart_payment.list", array($shoppingCartId));
  } catch(Exception $ex){
     echo '<br />payment method'.$ex->getMessage();
  }

  $paymentMethod = array(
    'po_number' => null,
    'method' => $resultPaymentMethods[0]['code'],
    'cc_cid' => trim($_POST["cc_cid"]),
    'cc_owner' => trim($_POST["cc_owner"]),
    'cc_number' => trim($_POST["cc_number"]),
    'cc_type' => trim($_POST["cc_type"]), // AE = American Express, VI = Visa, MC = MasterCard, DI = Discover
    'cc_exp_year' => trim($_POST["cc_exp_year"]),
    'cc_exp_month' => trim($_POST["cc_exp_month"])
  );

  echo "<br />Method: ".$resultPaymentMethods[0]['code'];
  echo "<br />Cvv: ".$_POST["cc_cid"];
  echo "<br />Owner name: ".$_POST["cc_owner"];
  echo "<br />Card Number: ".$_POST["cc_number"];
  echo "<br />Type: ".$_POST["cc_type"];
  echo "<br />Ex year: ".$_POST["cc_exp_year"];
  echo "<br />Ex Month: ".$_POST["cc_exp_month"];
  echo "<br />";
  try{
    $resultPaymentMethod = $proxy->call($sessionId, "cart_payment.method", array($shoppingCartId, $paymentMethod));
  } catch(Exception $ex){
    echo '<br />cart_payment.method'.$ex->getMessage();
  }

  try{
    $cart_info = $proxy->call($sessionId, "cart.info", $shoppingCartId);
    echo "<pre>"; print_R($cart_info);
  } catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo "<br /> cart info = ".$ex->getMessage();
  }

  $result = "";
  try{
    $resultOrderCreation = $proxy->call($sessionId, "cart.order", array($shoppingCartId));    
    $result = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'sales_order.addComment', array('orderIncrementId' => $resultOrderCreation, 'status' => 'complete'));
  } catch(Exception $ex){
    print_r($result);
    echo "<br /> order = ".$ex->getMessage();
  }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo "login = " . $ex->getMessage();
}
?>
```

we are testing with live authorize.net account (not in test mode). also one more thing manual orders are working fine.

Following is the response of cart.info

```
Array
(
    [store_id] => 1
    [created_at] => 2014-04-07 16:57:16
    [updated_at] => 2014-04-07 16:57:18
    [converted_at] => 
    [is_active] => 0
    [is_virtual] => 0
    [is_multi_shipping] => 0
    [items_count] => 1
    [items_qty] => 1.0000
    [orig_order_id] => 0
    [store_to_base_rate] => 1.0000
    [store_to_quote_rate] => 1.0000
    [base_currency_code] => USD
    [store_currency_code] => USD
    [quote_currency_code] => USD
    [grand_total] => 0.0100
    [base_grand_total] => 0.0100
    [checkout_method] => customer
    [customer_id] => 241
    [customer_tax_class_id] => 3
    [customer_group_id] => 1
    [customer_email] => testing123456@gmail.com
    [customer_prefix] => 
    [customer_firstname] => ritesh
    [customer_middlename] => 
    [customer_lastname] => patadiya
    [customer_suffix] => 
    [customer_dob] => 
    [customer_note] => 
    [customer_note_notify] => 1
    [customer_is_guest] => 0
    [remote_ip] => 
    [applied_rule_ids] => 
    [reserved_order_id] => 
    [password_hash] => 
    [coupon_code] => 
    [global_currency_code] => USD
    [base_to_global_rate] => 1.0000
    [base_to_quote_rate] => 1.0000
    [customer_taxvat] => 
    [customer_gender] => 
    [subtotal] => 0.0100
    [base_subtotal] => 0.0100
    [subtotal_with_discount] => 0.0100
    [base_subtotal_with_discount] => 0.0100
    [is_changed] => 1
    [trigger_recollect] => 0
    [ext_shipping_info] => 
    [gift_message_id] => 
    [is_persistent] => 0
    [quote_id] => 800
    [shipping_address] => Array
        (
            [address_id] => 
            [quote_id] => 800
            [created_at] => 2014-04-07 16:57:17
            [updated_at] => 2014-04-07 16:57:18
            [customer_id] => 241
            [save_in_address_book] => 0
            [customer_address_id] => 
            [address_type] => shipping
            [email] => 
            [prefix] => 
            [firstname] => ritesh
            [middlename] => 
            [lastname] => patadiya
            [suffix] => 
            [company] => rb
            [street] => wall street
            [city] => rajkot
            [region] => gujarat
            [region_id] => 
            [postcode] => 4567892
            [country_id] => id
            [telephone] => 0123456789
            [fax] => 0123456789
            [same_as_billing] => 1
            [free_shipping] => 0
            [collect_shipping_rates] => 1
            [shipping_method] => 
            [shipping_description] => 
            [weight] => 0.0000
            [subtotal] => 0.0000
            [base_subtotal] => 0.0000
            [subtotal_with_discount] => 0.0000
            [base_subtotal_with_discount] => 0.0000
            [tax_amount] => 0.0000
            [base_tax_amount] => 0.0000
            [shipping_amount] => 0.0000
            [base_shipping_amount] => 0.0000
            [shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000
            [base_shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000
            [discount_amount] => 0.0000
            [base_discount_amount] => 0.0000
            [grand_total] => 0.0000
            [base_grand_total] => 0.0000
            [customer_notes] => 
            [applied_taxes] => a:0:{}
            [discount_description] => 
            [shipping_discount_amount] => 
            [base_shipping_discount_amount] => 
            [subtotal_incl_tax] => 0.0000
            [base_subtotal_total_incl_tax] => 
            [hidden_tax_amount] => 
            [base_hidden_tax_amount] => 
            [shipping_hidden_tax_amount] => 
            [base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt] => 
            [shipping_incl_tax] => 0.0000
            [base_shipping_incl_tax] => 0.0000
            [vat_id] => 
            [vat_is_valid] => 
            [vat_request_id] => 
            [vat_request_date] => 
            [vat_request_success] => 
            [gift_message_id] => 
        )

    [billing_address] => Array
        (
            [address_id] => 
            [quote_id] => 800
            [created_at] => 2014-04-07 16:57:17
            [updated_at] => 2014-04-07 16:57:18
            [customer_id] => 241
            [save_in_address_book] => 0
            [customer_address_id] => 
            [address_type] => billing
            [email] => testing123456@gmail.com
            [prefix] => 
            [firstname] => ritesh
            [middlename] => 
            [lastname] => patadiya
            [suffix] => 
            [company] => rb
            [street] => wall street
            [city] => rajkot
            [region] => gujarat
            [region_id] => 
            [postcode] => 123456
            [country_id] => id
            [telephone] => 0123456789
            [fax] => 0123456789
            [same_as_billing] => 0
            [free_shipping] => 0
            [collect_shipping_rates] => 0
            [shipping_method] => 
            [shipping_description] => 
            [weight] => 0.0000
            [subtotal] => 0.0100
            [base_subtotal] => 0.0100
            [subtotal_with_discount] => 0.0000
            [base_subtotal_with_discount] => 0.0000
            [tax_amount] => 0.0000
            [base_tax_amount] => 0.0000
            [shipping_amount] => 0.0000
            [base_shipping_amount] => 0.0000
            [shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000
            [base_shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000
            [discount_amount] => 0.0000
            [base_discount_amount] => 0.0000
            [grand_total] => 0.0100
            [base_grand_total] => 0.0100
            [customer_notes] => 
            [applied_taxes] => a:0:{}
            [discount_description] => 
            [shipping_discount_amount] => 0.0000
            [base_shipping_discount_amount] => 0.0000
            [subtotal_incl_tax] => 0.0100
            [base_subtotal_total_incl_tax] => 
            [hidden_tax_amount] => 0.0000
            [base_hidden_tax_amount] => 0.0000
            [shipping_hidden_tax_amount] => 0.0000
            [base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt] => 
            [shipping_incl_tax] => 0.0000
            [base_shipping_incl_tax] => 0.0000
            [vat_id] => 
            [vat_is_valid] => 
            [vat_request_id] => 
            [vat_request_date] => 
            [vat_request_success] => 
            [gift_message_id] => 
        )

    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 1307
                    [quote_id] => 800
                    [created_at] => 2014-04-07 16:57:17
                    [updated_at] => 2014-04-07 16:57:17
                    [product_id] => 99
                    [store_id] => 1
                    [parent_item_id] => 
                    [is_virtual] => 1
                    [sku] => DEM001R
                    [name] => Demo Monthly Subscription (Do Not Purchase)
                    [description] => 
                    [applied_rule_ids] => 
                    [additional_data] => 
                    [free_shipping] => 0
                    [is_qty_decimal] => 0
                    [no_discount] => 0
                    [weight] => 
                    [qty] => 1
                    [price] => 0.0100
                    [base_price] => 0.0100
                    [custom_price] => 
                    [discount_percent] => 0.0000
                    [discount_amount] => 0.0000
                    [base_discount_amount] => 0.0000
                    [tax_percent] => 0.0000
                    [tax_amount] => 0.0000
                    [base_tax_amount] => 0.0000
                    [row_total] => 0.0100
                    [base_row_total] => 0.0100
                    [row_total_with_discount] => 0.0000
                    [row_weight] => 0.0000
                    [product_type] => subscription_virtual
                    [base_tax_before_discount] => 
                    [tax_before_discount] => 
                    [original_custom_price] => 
                    [redirect_url] => 
                    [base_cost] => 
                    [price_incl_tax] => 0.0100
                    [base_price_incl_tax] => 0.0100
                    [row_total_incl_tax] => 0.0100
                    [base_row_total_incl_tax] => 0.0100
                    [hidden_tax_amount] => 0.0000
                    [base_hidden_tax_amount] => 0.0000
                    [gift_message_id] => 
                    [weee_tax_disposition] => 0.0000
                    [weee_tax_row_disposition] => 0.0000
                    [base_weee_tax_disposition] => 0.0000
                    [base_weee_tax_row_disposition] => 0.0000
                    [weee_tax_applied] => a:0:{}
                    [weee_tax_applied_amount] => 0.0000
                    [weee_tax_applied_row_amount] => 0.0000
                    [base_weee_tax_applied_amount] => 0.0000
                    [base_weee_tax_applied_row_amnt] => 
                    [qty_options] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [tax_class_id] => 0
                    [is_recurring] => 
                    [has_error] => 
                )

        )

    [payment] => Array
        (
            [payment_id] => 
            [quote_id] => 800
            [created_at] => 2014-04-07 16:57:18
            [updated_at] => 2014-04-07 16:57:18
            [method] => authorizenet
            [cc_type] => VI
            [cc_number_enc] => 
            [cc_last4] => 5636
            [cc_cid_enc] => 
            [cc_owner] => Hardik Raval
            [cc_exp_month] => 11
            [cc_exp_year] => 2021
            [cc_ss_owner] => 
            [cc_ss_start_month] => 
            [cc_ss_start_year] => 
            [po_number] => 
            [additional_data] => 
            [cc_ss_issue] => 
            [additional_information] => Array
                (
                )

            [paypal_payer_id] => 
            [paypal_payer_status] => 
            [paypal_correlation_id] => 
        )

)
```

Getting this error: Credit card number mismatch with credit card type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10716297/158325

Comment: This means, if you are not PCI-DSS certified you should _NEVER_ have the cc number, so you can't send it to the API. If you are certified, you can "just save the cc number" and everything is fine.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt feel free to add an answer here if you have time :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not so into PCI-DSS but long story short (and maybe wrong! ;-))

To save CC numbers, the credit card companies expect, that your application and infrastructure is PCI-DSS certified. [More can be found about this on wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard)

So to "save" the cc number at any time (e.g. sending it via form to the server, "saving" it in the memory and just forward it to any credit card processing company) or just save it and then process it manually, you need this certification.

That said, I think that Authorize.net is implemented as pci-dss conform as possible, which means, the data is sent to authorize.net and not saved.