# Placing orders programmatically from 3rd party ordering system

Tags: sales-order, web-services

Before I start pulling my hair out with this one as I think its going to be a complicated one I would really appreciate someones advice.

The current situation is a company I'm working on makes all of their orders over the telephone and put into a backend ordering system. 
I've built a Magento frontend that I'm going to roll out to their existing customers who are all on Purchase Order numbers. No payment needed!

The customer will be able to place an order through Magento which is fine. If the customer makes a telephone order though, the order will be placed directly into the 3rd party backend ordering system. 
I want to keep a full track of all orders placed so customers can see all order history in Magento.

I essentially want to be able to have the 3rds party system spit out order information to csv or DB and have Magento pick up the order information and create the order within Magento.
That is it in its most simple form.

Is there a best practice for this?

Would really appreciate your help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Magento API webservice. Please take a look on this similar post [how to create order using magento web services in php](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/how-to-create-order-using-magento-web-services-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this [guide](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/) from Inchoo to achieve what you are looking fro with a CSV/XML/SQL file and maybe a cron running every X amount of time to pickup the new orders and import them.